# DataFrame column with Timestamps, need to localize multiple different timezones (AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values)

Tags: pandas, datetime

I've got a DataFrame (6M rows) with 2 columns, one column contains local time (timezone naive) and the other contains the timezone. Something like this:

```
|    | SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE   | ORIGIN_TZ           |
|---:|:----------------------|:--------------------|
|  0 | 2020-11-30 11:40:00   | America/New_York    |
|  1 | 2020-11-30 16:51:00   | America/New_York    |
|  2 | 2020-11-30 09:05:00   | America/Chicago     |
|  3 | 2020-11-30 19:18:00   | America/Chicago     |
|  4 | 2020-11-30 10:36:00   | America/New_York    |
|  5 | 2020-11-30 12:10:00   | America/Los_Angeles |
|  6 | 2020-11-30 16:05:00   | America/New_York    |
|  7 | 2020-11-30 12:14:00   | America/New_York    |
|  8 | 2020-11-30 16:05:00   | America/New_York    |
|  9 | 2020-11-30 12:40:00   | America/Chicago     |
```

I'm trying to localize each row of `SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE` using the a `for` routine that subsets the `df` by each timezone, adds the timezone, and keeps looping:

```py
for tz in df['ORIGIN_TZ'].unique():
    mask_tz = (df['ORIGIN_TZ'] == tz)
    df.loc[mask_tz,'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'] = df.loc[mask_tz,'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'].dt.tz_localize(tz)
```

Oddly enough, *sometimes* it works and *sometimes* it returns the following error:

> **AttributeError**: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

When extracting the `SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE` column, the type is clearly datetime-like:

```
Name: SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE, Length: 5714008, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Do you know how to solve this? Is it possible to have more than 1 timezone per column?

Here's code to replicate thee sample df:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE': {0: pd.Timestamp('2020-11-30 10:15:00'), 1: pd.Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:55:00'), 2: pd.Timestamp('2020-11-30 06:00:00'), 3: pd.Timestamp('2020-11-30 16:23:00'), 4: pd.Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:35:00'), 5: pd.Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:00:00'), 6: pd.Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:50:00'), 7: pd.Timestamp('2020-11-30 13:45:00'), 8: pd.Timestamp('2020-11-30 10:15:00'), 9: pd.Timestamp('2020-11-30 20:00:00')}, 'ORIGIN_TZ': {0: 'America/New_York', 1: 'America/New_York', 2: 'America/Denver', 3: 'America/New_York', 4: 'America/Chicago', 5: 'America/Chicago', 6: 'America/Los_Angeles', 7: 'America/Chicago', 8: 'America/New_York', 9: 'America/Los_Angeles'}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you do:

```
df.loc[mask_tz,'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'] = df.loc[mask_tz,'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'].dt.tz_localize(tz)
```

your column turns into object dtype and the next `.dt` access fails. Try to work on a copy:

```
s = df['SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'].copy()
for tz in df['ORIGIN_TZ'].unique():
    mask_tz = (df['ORIGIN_TZ'] == tz)
    df.loc[mask_tz,'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'] = s.loc[mask_tz].dt.tz_localize(tz)
```

Then `df.loc[0,'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE']` would give:

```
Timestamp('2020-11-30 10:15:00-0500', tz='America/New_York')
```

Your `SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE` column is still `object` dtype though.